# UI/UX Design tool for developers

Tags: sketch, design, user-interface

I'm currently using [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/index.html) for wireframing and mockup in my company where I work as a developer, and I love using it because it gets me off the ground in no time.
However, it does sometimes falls short on the more *polished* design, which essentially means taking it from first conceptual wireframe (crude design) to a more one-to-one design (fine design).

I know about and have tried Sketch, Adobe XD, Figma, etc. but they all seem to be focused on designers and that I'm not (spending too much time in e.g. Sketch for just simple tasks). Ideally what I'm looking for is an UI design application like Balsamiq with complete HTML UI/Component library but with more control of their individual properties.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you seek for something like [Framer X](https://www.framer.com/)

Framer X, the newest version of Framer introduces the in-built use of React components to allow designers get closer to super high-fidelity prototyping. Framer's premise is that code can be used to hack together greater design prototypes. [Source](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/get-to-know-framer-x-the-react-ui-creator#toc-what-is-framer-x-)